# In Angular 9 how to allow only one toggle in div to be active at a given time?

Tags: javascript, angular, toggle

I have three toggles in a div, each of them representing a different homepage view. How would I allow only one toggle to be active at a given time, so for example when the myCalendar toggle is clicked the myFavourites and myProjects toggles are turned off, presuming one of them was active. I found many solutions with ngDisabled with AngularJS but none for Angular 9.

```
<div class="float-left d-flex align-items-center">    
    <span class="mx-2">
        <or-toggle-button id="myCalender" (changed)="updateFavouriteList()" [(ngModel)]="settings.myCalender" icon="fas fa-calendar-week fa-2x" iconTooltip="My Favourites"></or-toggle-button>
        <or-toggle-button id="myFavourites" (changed)="updateFavouriteList()" [(ngModel)]="settings.myFavourites" icon="far fa-star fa-2x" iconTooltip="My Favourites"></or-toggle-button>               
        <or-toggle-button id="myProjects" (changed)="updateProjectList()" [(ngModel)]="settings.myProjects" icon="fa-user fa-2x" iconTooltip="My Projects"></or-toggle-button>
      </span>              
    </div>
```

e.g One of the functions

```
updateFavouriteList() {
    if (this.settings.myFavourites) {
    // READ FROM MODEL IF FAVOURITE TOGGLE IS ACTIVE/INACTIVE
    this.projects = this.fulllist.filter(
        e => e.isFavourite === false
        );
        } else {
        this.projects = this.fulllist;
     }
    this.saveViewSettings();
  }
```

Comment: Only the selected one will be active?

Comment: @ConnorsFan yes, so only one may be active at a time.

Comment: So, the user cannot change his selection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go for ngSwitch

```
<container-element [ngSwitch]="currentPage">
  <some-element *ngSwitchCase="page1">...</some-element>
  <some-element *ngSwitchCase="page2">...</some-element>
...
   <some-element *ngSwitchDefault>...</some-element>
</container-element>
```

Then in component create some function that sets 'this.currentPage' equals to the one you want to display.

See angular docs for further info :)

Comment: yes,right. toggles should stay outside the switch. if they have to stay inside, each page should have the toggle set and they could be disabled if toggle.name !== currentPage.name for example.